# Is there any way to check if an argument exists

Tags: c#, control-flow

I am new to programming and I don't know how to check if an argument exists. For example, if an argument such as `args[2]` does not exist then run some code else do something else. Is there a means to achieve this?

Comment: How does this relate to networking?

Comment: This is not related to networking.  The underlying issue which has already been asked is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235754/quickest-way-of-checking-if-arguments-contain-anything-inside

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming "not exists" means that the args[2] would return a Index out of range exception, check the length of the args array:

```
if (args.Length == 3)
{
    //Do stuff since args[2] exists
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

If you mean args[2] is null, then just check that

```
if (args[2] != null)
{
    //Do stuff since args[2] exists
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: In the first example, you could use >= 3 if you are ok with more arguments as well.